# Altium error at compilation

Tags: altium

I got this error in Altium when I try to compile schematic. i don't understand what is the problem exactly. I have searched online and didn't find any solution so far. does anybody already had this problem ?

[image]

Details of the error below
[image]
This is the sheet

[image]

Here are the parameters of the page

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post a picture of you schematic please. Also Altium has a [recommendation](https://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/WorkspaceManager_Err-SameParameterContainingDifferentTypes((Same+Parameter+Containing+Different+Types))_AD) to avoid this error, did you try it?

Comment: Check the parameters of this component. You might have different types (Integer and string) for the same parameter! In other word, two same parameters with different types

Comment: the problem is altium doesn't mention where. it just give the sheet id, but not the components

Comment: How many different components do you have on that sheet?

Comment: Just check all components on that sheet and check if there is two same parameters with different types! that's it.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the error message is:

```
Same parameter contains different types <Object> <Types> ,
```

So the *Object* in your error message is 1 - MCU.SchDoc

Open up 1 - MCU.SchDoc, right click on the page background (not on a component), select Options, then Document Parameters.

Look through the list of parameters to see if you can find a parameter name duplicated, and delete the one that you don't want or is wrong.

Comment: I have done this but didn't find any parameters. I have added screenshot of the parameters option above in the thread. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe sheet number or something like that is automatically added as parameter by Altium Designer. Maybe you could change some of the parameters that could be integers to integer and see if that makes the error go away.

Comment: @chris the error message lists parameter DocumentNumber twice, once with the value 9, again with the value 3. And again in the sheet parameters it has the value 1. One of these could be an INTEGER, the others STRING.

Comment: You need to look at the unique IDs of the parameters. As you can see, two are listed in the error message details. One will be on the page you posted the pictures from, the other one might be on a different page. Double click on the parameters to open a property window that shows the UniqueID. Altium will report the page where the error occurred, not the page where the parameter was first set with different type. Once you've found one of the IDs look for a similar named parameter on a sheet or component with different type.

Comment: i didn't find any solution about this

Comment: @chris did you check the DocumentNumber on different sheets? Also, did you try the parameter manager (Tools menu)?

Comment: Yes I did. But in the parameters and options of the documen I have no Integer at all. I have only STRING. So I don't understand where this comes from

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it gives you this error if you haven't annotate the different schematic sheets! Go to 'Tool--> Annotation --> Number Schematic Sheets' and make the appropriate configuration for the different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this problem is quite tedious process, go through each page, check properties of every parameter, it should be same in all pages. I was having the issue for document number and sheet number, which was set as string and integer in two different pages. After correcting them, the errors stopped.

Good luck

Comment: one more update, this issue has nothing to do with Parameter manager :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2 year old post but I've just had the exact same issue in AD 18.1.9 so thought it would be worth noting my solution

The solution for me was relating to templates:

Go to Design -> Templates
Select a new template (either your own or use Altium built in ones under general)

Then once you're at the update template prompt select All schematic documents in current project and replace all matching parameters

As shown here:

[image: Update Template prompt]

Just like yourself I went through every parameter by hand an could not find any differences / issues. This seemed to be the only way to reset them all.

After doing this you will need to go back through each sheet and enter your parameters by hand

My guess to why this works is that it seems Altium hides certain parameters such as sheet unique ids. Updating the template seems to reset these parameters causing the compilation to go away

Let me know if this works, id be interested to hear back